# Select users and groups for specific account

Tags: mysql, sql

For following tables, I'd like to select all users and their groups for a specific account.

```
USERS 
-id
-name
-groupid
-accountid


GROUPS 
-id
-name
-accountid
```

I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT 
USERS.ID,
USERS.NAME,
GROUPS.ID,
GROUPS.NAME,    
FROM GROUPS JOIN USERS ON USERS.ACCOUNTID= GROUPS.ACCOUNTID
WHERE GROUPS.ACCOUNTID=1
```

For some reason results are repeated 3 times(which is the number of group). Each user is displayed 3 times with different GROUPID.

**update** If I join on GROUPID instead, like it was suggested. I get the following. As you can see only a single user is displayed per group even though there are more than one user in a group.

```
USER_ID  GROUP_ID     GROUP_NAME        NAME
42            6        Teacher      John E. 
59            8        Student      Bill W.
```

Comment: try using DISTINCT in your query...since your results are correct but only problem is that they are repeated i suggest you try using DISTINCT

Comment: That was my guess too. I did SELECT DISTINCT GROUP.ID.... but it returned the same result set.

Comment: Please take note you should put USERS as primary table instead of GROUPS when doing join.

Comment: @sel you mean on DISTINCT statement do SELECT DISTINCT USERS.ID... ?

Comment: @dev.e.loper . USE `FROM USERS JOIN GROUPS ON USERS.GROUPID= GROUPS.ID` . Please do not use `FROM GROUPS JOIN USERS ON USERS.GROUPID= GROUPS.ID` The first query use USERS as primary table whereas second query use GROUPS as primary table.

Comment: I did that. I'm getting same result, where I only get first user out of that group.

Comment: Could you see if  [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3afee/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3afee/1) is the sample data as yours? That is my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each User is displayed 3 times with different GROUPID due to you join on the ACCOUNTID instead of GROUPID.

You could try the below ie join on the GROUPID.

```
SELECT 
USERS.ID,
USERS.NAME,
GROUPS.ID,
GROUPS.NAME    
FROM USERS JOIN GROUPS ON USERS.GROUPID= GROUPS.ID
WHERE GROUPS.ACCOUNTID=1
```

UPDATED:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3afee/1

Comment: When I do that groups are displayed. But not all users are displayed for those groups. It lists 3 groups and a column where user's name is displayed. There is a user name but there are more users in that group.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to sqlfiddle